# Number of nested environments in a two-column document

Tags: warnings, nesting

When you use a two-column document does the number of nested list environments you can place gets reduced?  I thought that you could use 6 nested environments before LaTeX "complain" about being too deeply nested, but now LaTeX "complain" when I try to use the 5th nested environment.

Comment: There is a limit on nesting list based environments (six); at most four of them can be `enumerate` or `itemize`. Are you really sure you want to nest so many lists in a two column document? The line width of the deepest one will be very narrow.

Comment: @egreg I use 3 but I tried it out of curiosity and I got that warning.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: @egreg An example of what? I used out of curiosity 4 enumerate environments and got that warning...You said that 4 was the limit so you basically answered. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit of nesting six list based environments (including, for instance, `quotation`, `quote`, `description`, `enumerate` and `itemize`).

However at most four of them can be `enumerate` or `itemize`.

The following example fails because there are five nested `enumerate` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{quotation}
Level 1
\begin{enumerate}
\item Level 2
\begin{enumerate}
\item Level 3
\begin{enumerate}
\item Level 4
\begin{enumerate}
\item Level 5
\begin{enumerate}
\item Level 6
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

However, if the deepest `enumerate` is changed into `itemize`, no error shows up. The `twocolumn` option is irrelevant for the task.

If another level is added, `quote` in the example, the error shows up again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{quotation}
Level 1
\begin{enumerate}
\item Level 2
\begin{enumerate}
\item Level 3
\begin{enumerate}
\item Level 4
\begin{enumerate}
\item Level 5
\begin{itemize}
\item Level 6
\begin{quote}
Level 7
\end{quote}
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

This stops with

```
! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \begin{quote}
```

Non list based environments don't have such a limitation, but only the general TeX limit on semantic nest size (default 500 in TeX Live), that is, the number of open groups.